Why are all backslashes and some characters missing in text file modified with sed on Windows?
I downloaded sed.exe from GnuWin32 and tried to use it in my batch script. However, sed returns a different string than what I expected.
I tried to use a different delimiter and using the -b flag, but nothing happened.
My batch script:
@echo off
set "scriptDir=%~dp0"
"%scriptDir%sed\sed.exe" "s|Windows XP (x64, cloud).vmdk|%scriptDir%Windows XP (x64, cloud).vmdk|" "Windows XP (x64, cloud).vmx"

What I expect to be written in the changed line:
scsi0:0.fileName = "C:\Users\Maksio\OneDrive\Windows XP (x64)\Windows XP (x64, cloud).vmdk"

What is actually written:
scsi0:0.fileName = "C:SERSMAKSIOONEDRIVEWINDOWS XP (X64)WINDOWS XP (X64, CLOUD).VMDK"


It would be a good idea reading the sed manual, especially but not only the chapter 3.3 The s Command. The backslash character \ has a special meaning in the search and replace regular expressions. Each backslash must be escaped with one more backslash to be interpreted as literal character.
It is additionally necessary to escape each & in script directory path with \ to be interpreted as literal ampersand character.
That is described in the sed manual with the paragraph:

To include a literal \, &, or newline in the final replacement, be sure to precede the desired \, &, or newline in the replacement with a \.

The batch file should be therefore:
@echo off
set "scriptDir=%~dp0"
set "EscapedScriptDir=%scriptDir:\=\\%"
set "EscapedScriptDir=%EscapedScriptDir:&=\&%"
"%scriptDir%sed\sed.exe" "s|Windows XP (x64, cloud).vmdk|%EscapedScriptDir%Windows XP (x64, cloud).vmdk|" "Windows XP (x64, cloud).vmx"

Run in a command prompt window set /? and read the entire output help for an explanation of the two string substitutions used here to escape each backslash with one more backslash and each ampersand with a backslash in the script directory path.
